# find the minimum number of words(distance) between repeated occurrences of a search string in the input string

Tags: python

Here are test cases for the code:

1. - string - `'Tim had been saying that he had been there'`
   - search - `'had'`
   - expected output - 4
2. - string - `'he got what he got and what he wanted'`
   - search - `'he'`
   - expected out - 2

```
def return_distance(input, search):
    words = input.split()
    distance = None
    
    indx = []
    if not input or not search:
        return None
    else:
        if words.count(search) >1:
            indx = [ index for index, word in enumerate(words) if word == search]
            distance = indx[1] - indx[0]
            for i  in range(len(indx)-1):
                distance = min(distance, indx[i+1] - indx[i])-1
    
    return distance
```

I am thinking how to optimize the code. I admit it is poorly written.

Comment: So the code works and you want to optimize it? Optimize for readability, performance...?

Comment: Thanks for formatting @ggorlen

Comment: yes, more like pythonic

Comment: Before optimizing I'd rather make it **correct**. You get a name error for `search_str`. And after fixing it, you for example fail `return_distance('x o x x o x', 'x')` by returning `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error in the code. Corrected it @superb rain

Comment: Now you fail your own second example. Brilliant. Also, not sure what the policy here is about changing code like that in questions, as it makes answers addressing it look silly/wrong.

Comment: @superbrain - I hear your concern. Wish everyone were as brilliant as you. Let's help each other who really wants to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
def min_distance_between_words(sentence, word):
    idxes = [i for i, e in enumerate(sentence.split()) if e == word]
    return min([y - x - 1 for x, y in zip(idxes, idxes[1:])])
```

This splits the input sentence, makes a list of every index that matches the target word, then iterates over this list to compute the differences between each index and returns the minimum difference.

Since behavior is unspecified when the sentence doesn't have a word, it raises an error but you can add a check for this and return the value of your choice if desired using `min`'s `default` parameter:

```
def min_distance_between_words(sentence, word):
    idxes = [i for i, e in enumerate(sentence.split()) if e == word]
    return min([y - x - 1 for x, y in zip(idxes, idxes[1:])], default=None)
```

As an aside, naming a variable `input` overwrites a builtin and `return_distance` is a rather ambiguous name for a function.

Adding a precondition for parameters for `None` as done with `if not input or not search:` is not typically done in Python (we assume caller will always pass in a string and adhere to the function's contract).

If you want to generalize this further, move the `split()` duty to the domain of the caller which enables the function to operate on arbitrary iterables:

```
def min_distance_between_occurrences(it, target):
    idxes = [i for i, e in enumerate(it) if e == target]
    return min([y - x - 1 for x, y in zip(idxes, idxes[1:])], default=None)
```

Call with:

```
min_distance_between_occurrences("a b c a".split(), "a")
min_distance_between_occurrences([(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2)], (1, 2))
```

---

Refactoring aside, as pointed out in the comments, the original code isn't correct. Issues include:

- `search_str` does not exist. You probably meant `search`.
- `distance` and `min_dist` don't really work together. Pick one or the other and use it for all minimum calculations.
- `min(min_dist, indx[i+1] - indx[i])-1` subtracts 1 in the wrong place, throwing off the count.

Here's a potential fix for these issues:

```
def return_distance(input, search):
    words = input.split()
    distance = None

    if words.count(search) > 1:
        indx = [index for index, word in enumerate(words) if word == search]
        distance = indx[1] - indx[0] - 1
        #                           ^^^^

        for i  in range(len(indx) - 1):
            distance = min(distance, indx[i+1] - indx[i] - 1)
            #                                           ^^^^
            
    return distance
```

Comment: Thanks a lot with a beautiful explanation @ggorlen

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) with list comprehension on `indx`

`min_dist = min([(indx[i+1] - indx[i]-1) for i in range(len(indx)-1) ])`